# Hide the context menu in <audio>

Tags: html, css, html5-audio

I'm creating a php program for my son, where I use the component audio. But I want to prevent him from using the context menu to download the audio file.

The property controls shows or hides everything, so it's not what I need. And I want something more simple than a javascript function.

I use it this way :

```
<audio controls src="music.wav"></audio>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `controlsList="nodownload"` to the `<audio>` tag to hide the download button (at least on Chrome)

```html
<div class="positionRelative">
  <audio controls src="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/wav/viola.wav" controlsList="nodownload"></audio>
  <div class="styleAudio"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't find this in the documentations.

Comment: @Myosotis No problemo, Thanks for accepting the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution : I hide the right end of the audio component :

```
<div class="positionRelative">
  <audio controls src="music.wav"></audio>
  <div class="styleAudio"></div>
</div>
```

The styles:

```
.positionRelative { position : relative; }
.styleAudio
{
  background : #F2F2F2;
  position : absolute;
  top : 0;
  right : 0;
  width : 2.8em;
  height : 3.4em;
  border-radius : 2.8em;
}
```